# Java- Accesing instances of a class in a method

Tags: java, methods, instance

I have to write a code for class that takes in a temperature value, converts it to kelvin, and then determines if this is greater than, equal to, less than, or whatever to another entered temp. It has to say true or false for each of the boolean possibilities. I can't get it to compare the temperature that is set as t1, with the temperature t that the boolean methods take as a parameter? Any suggestions?

```
public class Temperature {
    
   public double degrees;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

}
       
    
    Temperature (){
   degrees=0;
}
       
Temperature (double enteredtemp){
    degrees = enteredtemp;
}
Temperature (double enteredtemp,char scale ){
   Temperature t1 = new Temperature (enteredtemp, scale);
   t1.set(enteredtemp,scale);

    
}
public void set (double enteredtemp, char scale){
       if (scale == 'r'|| scale == 'R'){ degrees = (enteredtemp/(9/5));}
       else if (scale == 'c'|| scale == 'C') {degrees = enteredtemp+273.15;}
       else if (scale =='F'|| scale == 'f'){degrees = ((enteredtemp+459.67)*9/5);}
       
    
    
}

public double get(){
    return degrees;
}
 public double get(char scale){
    if (scale == 'c'|| scale == 'C'){degrees = (degrees-273.15);}
    else if (scale == 'r'||scale == 'R'){degrees = (degrees*(9/5));}
    else if (scale == 'f'|| scale == 'F'){degrees = (degrees*(9/5)-459.67);}
    return (degrees);
            }
 
 
 public boolean isLessThan(Temperature t){
 
 if (t.get() < t1.get())
 return true;
 else {
 return false;
 }
 
 }
 public boolean isGreaterThan(Temperature t){
     if (t.get() > t1.get()) {
     return true;
     }
     else {
     return false;
     }
 }
 public boolean isEqual(Temperature t){
     if ((Math.abs(t.get() - t1.get()))<=10E-12){
     return true;
     }
     else {
     return false;
     }
     
 }
 
 public boolean isGreaterThanOrEqual(Temperature t){
     if (t.get() >= t1.get()){
     return true;
     }
     else {
     return false;
     }
     
 }
 public boolean isLessThanorEqual(Temperature t){
     if (t.get() <= t1.get()){
     return true;
     }
     else {
     return false;
     }
 } 
}
```

Comment: Please see if [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25703535/3403161) also answers the question being raised by this thread (in case I suggest we close it as a duplicate).

Answer (score 0):

In your functions of this form:

```
public boolean isGreaterThan(Temperature t){
  if (t.get()>t1.get()) {return true;}
  else {return false;}
}
```

You are comparing `t` with a non-existent `t1`. You want to be comparing the current object (`this`) with `t`, the parameter you've been passed. You can also return the result of the comparison directly instead of using an `if` statement.

```
public boolean isGreaterThan(Temperature t){
  return this.get() > t.get();
}
```

Note also that in your constructor that takes two parameters, you're not setting your object properties at all: you're creating a new `t1`, setting its properties, and then discarding it. Call `this.set` rather than `t1.set`.

Comment: I don't understand what the this method does? This is for class, and there is a tester program that will use the constructor methods, and then the t that is tested through the boolean's is compared to this?

Comment: If you already have a `Temperature` called `t1`, and another one called `t2`, you can call `t1.isGreaterThan(t2)` to compare the two. But this doesn't make sense unless you already have these instances to make the comparison.

Comment: It's like asking someone: "Are you taller than Dave?" In order for the question to be meaningful, you need someone to ask the question to ("you"), and someone else to compare with ("Dave").

Answer (score 0):

#### Make it compile first

Your code as posted doesn't compile because you are using unknown variables like `t1` here:

> ```
> public boolean isGreaterThan(Temperature t){
>      if (t.get()>t1.get()) {return true;}
>      else {return false;}
>  }
> ```

You want to drop the `t1.` there.

#### Don't make changes in `get`

It's counter intuitive and a bad practice to have a method named `get` that changes the fields of a class. So instead of this:

> ```
> public double get(char scale) {
>   if (scale == 'c' || scale == 'C') {
>       degrees = (degrees - 273.15);
>   } else if (scale == 'r' || scale == 'R') {
>       degrees = (degrees * (9 / 5));
>   } else if (scale == 'f' || scale == 'F') {
>       degrees = (degrees * (9 / 5) - 459.67);
>   }
>   return (degrees);
> }
> ```

Rewrite like this:

```
public double get(char scale) {
    if (scale == 'c' || scale == 'C') {
        return degrees - 273.15;
    } else if (scale == 'r' || scale == 'R') {
        return degrees * 9 / 5;
    } else if (scale == 'f' || scale == 'F') {
        return degrees * 9 / 5 - 459.67;
    }
    return degrees;
}
```

I also removed unnecessary parentheses.

#### Simplify

Also, most of your methods could be greatly simplified, for example:

```
public boolean isLessThan(Temperature t) {
    return get() < t.get();
}

public boolean isGreaterThan(Temperature t) {
    return get() > t.get();
}

public boolean isEqual(Temperature t) {
    return Math.abs(t.get() - get()) <= 10E-12;
}

public boolean isGreaterThanOrEqual(Temperature t) {
    return get() >= t.get();
}

public boolean isLessThanOrEqual(Temperature t) {
    return get() <= t.get();
}
```

#### Improve

*(I know you commend your prof "doesn't like" `switch` (and he's wrong), but leaving this anyway for your reference.)*

I also recommend rewriting `set` like this:

```
public void set(double enteredtemp, char scale) {
    switch (scale) {
        case 'r':
        case 'R':
            degrees = (enteredtemp / (9 / 5));
            break;
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            degrees = enteredtemp + 273.15;
            break;
        case 'f':
        case 'F':
            degrees = ((enteredtemp + 459.67) * 9 / 5);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't rewrite it that way, even if it is more simple its for class and we have been instructed to write the set method a certain way. Prof hates swtich, break, and won't let us use case. I'm curious how to make sure the degrees are returned correctly. If I use the get method with it automatically go through the set method to find the degrees?

Comment: Fine. I added other improvements, see my updated answer.